# Can't Get Token Back + WebApi 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am following portions of [this tutorial](http://saifikram.com/2014/06/token-based-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-with-owin) and [this tutorial](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) but I can't get it to work. I get a 404 when I try to get a token back

Startup

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(config);
}

public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider()
    };

    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

}
```

}

SimpleAuthorizationServiceProvider

```
 public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {
            bool isValidUser = false;
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            if (context.UserName == "test" && context.Password == "test")
            {
                isValidUser = true;
            }

            if (!isValidUser)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                return;
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);

        }
    }
```

I try to go to `http://localhost:54690/token` in postman but I just get 404.

I don't really know what packages they really are using but these are the ones I have so far

```
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Cors" version="5.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin" version="2.2.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.OData" version="5.9.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OwinSelfHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Core" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Cors" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="2.1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Spatial" version="6.15.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I assume the code is the same as the code from the tutorial(s). Did you add breakpoints to verify that your code (like ConfigureOAuth) is actually executed? Did you verify the ports (http/https)? Do you use the POST method to get the token?

Comment: A mix of the 2 tutorials(though I have a feeling that one copied the other person). https just does not work. Postman is set to post but maybe I am doing that wrong in tutorial it says to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded. No breakpoints are hit in the statup file.

Comment: Seems like I was missing an nuget package.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the "Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" package.

I have no idea why this is needed as there do not seem to be any dependencies on it. The complete system will compile and run but you will get 404 errors unless you add in this package. Hope this does it for you.